# mutableCopy of nsmutuableArray, and autorelease it-crash

Tags: objective-c

I have this :

```
-(NSMutableArray*)setManch:(NSMutableArray*)data
{

    NSMutableArray *manch=[data mutableCopy] ;
     // some calculations on manch
    return manch;

}
```

If i try to do :

```
NSMutableArray *manch=[[data mutableCopy] autorelease] ;
```

I get a crash .

But, i have to `release` this copy somehow because I call this function again and again. How should I do that?

```
for(int k=0;k< count;k=k+2)
    {
        if(k==count-1)
            [manch addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:![[manch objectAtIndex:k] integerValue] ] ];
        else
            [manch insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:![[manch objectAtIndex:k] integerValue] ]     atIndex:k+1 ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use ARC.

But anyway. The autorelease is correct here. So your mistake is probably somewhere else. What does the error state exactly?

Probably the problem is the data IN your array. A simple copy call does NOT make deep copies. So if you're objects only exist in the first array, they will be released as soon as that array gets released. Debug your data: look what exists before and after that method call.

You should read about & understand memory management on ios:

General **Memory Management**:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i

Practical Management, especially **"Avoid Causing Deallocation of Objects You’re Using"**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1000922

Also read about **ARC**:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i

Comment: no error but it seems that when other class is trying to use this array that being return from this function , it is null....

Comment: is it maybe because this function is in classA and after i create an instance of classA, and use this function, i release that classA instance, so the copy is released twice ?  DOES RELEASE ON INSTANCE- CLEAR FROM MEMORY ALSO THE POINTERS WHICH ARE INSTANCE VARIABLES OF THAT CLASS ? I MEAN THE MEMORY WHICH THEY POINT TO ?

Comment: i have seen your update thanks a lot, but i dont get something, if i return that munch array as a pointer, and than it is being released- because of the autorelease, so others cant use it anymore, isnt that the problem here ?

Comment: so as you said, manch is being autoreleased when the function ends ,and its returned pointer becomes nil , am i right ?

Comment: no you are wrong. it gets released in the context where it is returned to, as soon as that context ends. whatever - the release is NOT the problem. You did understand the memory system, no? If not read about it. And also read about ARC. that would solve your issues easily. I will add some links to the answer.